# Flat image output in TileMill SVG export

Tags: export, tilemill, svg

I have created a map in TileMill using OSM data (~500 Mb) and modifying the CartoCSS to fit my use case. I need to export it as an SVG with all the different objects being vectors etc.

However, when I use the built-in `Export -> SVG` function, the result is only a flat image of the area I defined in the viewfinder.

[image: Tilemill export window]

Except for some Font warnings during the export process, there are no errors.
How can I obtain a vector image of my map?

Here is my export window in TileMill, the resulting image opened in Inkscape (showing that it is indeed only a flat image and not a collection of vectors) and the terminal output (showing no error, only warning).

[image: Inkscape single image]

[image: Terminal output]

Comment: I've added the images. The original .osm data is 500MB but I only try to export a small area of it.